# Is every real in $[0,1]$ a dyadic rational?

Tags: number-theory

I'm not a mathematician but I'm interested in dyadyc rationals in $[0,1]$. I know that $x \in [0,1]$ is dyadically rational iif it has a finite binary representation. I wanted to see how that works so I used the following codes: [f_d2b](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13899-floating-number-conversion-to-binary-and-vice-versa?focused=5235815&tab=function), and the code from the accepted answer [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/25549-convert-floating-point-to-binary).  For the first code all the reals $\in [0,1]$ had a finite representation, so I thought that maybe the code is built to render a finte number of digits. In the second code you can specifie the number of digits you want so I set it to 1000, and I noticed that every real `0:0.0001:0.9999` has a finite representation. I searched and I couldn't find anywhere that confirms that every real $\in [0,1]$ is dyadically rational.

Comment: Not every real number in this interval is rational.

Comment: No, because the rationals and hence the dyadic rationals are countable. But the dyadic rationals are dense in $[0,1]$ so every real number in this interval is a limit of dyadic rationals.

Comment: Is there any way to know if a real $\in [0,1]$ is dyadically rational in Matlab?

Comment: More importantly, how to detect if a real in dyadically irrational?

Comment: How to detect if a real is "dyadically irrational" --- If the real is irrational, then the real is dyadically irrational. If the real is rational, then reduce the fraction representation to lowest terms; if denominator a power of 2, then it's dyadically rational; otherwise, it's dyadically irrational.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, Could you please give me 2 examples of 2 reals (one is dyadically rational and the other one is not), and how to detect if they are dyadically irratioanl

Comment: $111/48$ is a dyadic rational because when reduced to lowest terms it is $37/16$ and the denominator $16$ is a power of $2.$ On the other hand, $205/85$ is not a dyadic rational because when reduced to lowest terms it is $41/17$ and the denominator $17$ is not a power of $2.$ Also, neither $\pi$ nor $\sqrt 2$ are dyadic rationals because each is an irrational number. (Note: A dyadic rational number is a special type of rational number, so if the number is not rational then it cannot be a dyadic rational.)

Comment: Dyadic rationals are a dense subset of $[0,1]$, but they are countable, hence almost every element of $[0,1]$ is not a dyadic rational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pound a nail with a nuclear bomb:

> Denseness of irrational numbers: Let $a$ and $b$ be any two rational numbers such that $a < b$. Then there exists a real number $c$ such that $a < c < b$ and $c$ is irrational.

Simply put, your answer is very well no.

There does not exist a computer that doesnt conventionally (in normal circumstances) store numbers as anything other than dyadic rationals. So short of a weird "rational" data type storing actual numerical pairs to represent quotients, you will always get a dyadic rational. Next time consider a simple counter-example. $0.1$ is not a dyadic rational. There. You're done and it is the simplest counter-example used when learning about base 2 in computer science courses. I suggest you read up on the IEEE floating point number system for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: dyadic rationals are dense too

Comment: I found this on Wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Dyadic_rational.svg/300px-Dyadic_rational.svg.png , and it says "Dyadic rationals in the interval from 0 to 1.
". Is there a list of dyadic rationals $\in [0,1]$  already available?

Comment: When I see a new programmer using a float or double to store money, I get them to put 0.01 in a variable, add it to another 100 times, and compare the total to 1.00.  They are shocked that the comparison fails.  They have not actually put 0.01 in the variable but a value that is very nearly but not quite 0.01.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is just approximating real numbers with its binary floating-point numbers (dyadic rationals). You can approximate any real number arbitrarily closely with a finite binary sequence, but never exactly for irrational numbers e.g. $1/\sqrt 2$ or even rational numbers like $1/3$. You can, however, represent all real numbers in that interval by an infinite binary sequence.

Dyadic rationals are just $\frac a{2^b}$ where $a,b$ are integers.

Comment: I found this on Wikipedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Dyadic_rational.svg/300px-Dyadic_rational.svg.png , and it says "Dyadic rationals in the interval from 0 to 1. ". Is there a list of dyadic rationals ∈[0,1] already available?

Comment: No, there are infinitely many of them. You can't list them all (at least not on a picture)